# How to map a saved texture directly on a QuickItem & display it?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qquickitem, qopenglfunctions

In my `Qt app` with `C++`, I am using a `QQuickItem` derived class to display textures which are produced on every frame render by running some filters on each frame render. this works fine.

Next, I used the `takeTexture` method provided by `QOpenGLFramebufferObject` to save some textures & display them back whenever required. These saved textures are of type `GLuint`s. I am able to display it back using the normal OpenGL rendering pipeline. It works well.

But, Is there a way I can avoid the rendering pipeline calls & **map this saved texture on GPU memory directly to my `QQuickItem`**?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a QQuickItem that renders the contents of a texture?

Comment: yes in a way. I see some methods like [setTexture](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsgsimpletexturenode.html#setTexture) available in QSGSimpleTextureNode. But not able to figure out how to pass the `GLuint` that I got from [takeTexture](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglframebufferobject.html#takeTexture) into some method which can take the texture & display it on a QQuickItem.

Comment: discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32162215/adding-a-background-image-to-a-qquickitem) suggests how to create a `QSGTexture` from an image & `setTexture` using it. is there a way I can create a `QSGTexture` from a Gluint & then call `setTexture` on the window ?

Comment: `item->window()->createTextureFromId(texture_id)` will give you a `QSGTexture`. Then combine it with a geometry node, geometry and a material node.

Comment: @peppe is it possible for you to give a sample of what to do after creating a `QSGTexture` out of the `GLuint texture_id` ? Is some way I can tell my method `updatePaintNode` to use this `QSGTexture` & render it ? or if there is a better way, please suggest

Comment: Check out some of the examples that create a custom QQuickItem. Yes, you need to override `updatePaintNode` and return a minimal tree of nodes to render your texture. At a minimum, you need geometry (a quad) and a material that draws your texture.

Comment: @peppe thanks `updatePaintNode` with a correct `TextureNode` worked. You can pls post the same as an answer. it will great if can explain some more about how the Qt scene graph works along with your answer (iff u wish)